# How to store special leters in mysql from username discord?

Tags: java, mysql, discord

Im saving information about discord users in to my MySQL database, i have no problem when user has standard nickname like "John" But when they have special characters like "" Or "ѕ т". Where i should change encoding to support those chars? Error which i got:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\xBD\xF0\x9D...' for column 'discord_name' at row 1
```

In past i try to change JdbcURL to this:

```
jdbc:mysql://" + HOST + "/" + DB + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8
```

I added useUnicode and characterEndocing to UTF8(i try utf-8) and in phpmyadmin  i setup collaction to: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Connecting to database with Hikari:

```
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + HOST + "/" + DB + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8");
        config.setUsername(USER);
        config.setPassword(PASS);
```

And my Query:

```
INSERT INTO `discord_user`" +
                        "(`discord_id`,`discord_name`," +
                        " `is_connected`, `code`, `update_at`, `create_at`," +
                        "`join_date`) VALUES " +
                        "($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
```

I expect to save user nickname in readable human format. i don't want to serialized it. Actual i just skip putting nickname into database.